# C++ Make show where include is searching for files

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am trying to compile a section of a library with `cmake` and `make`. I am getting the error when I run `Make` that the include is failing:

`/home/user/Sean/PCL/pcl/apps/src/face_detection/openni_face_detection.cpp:9:57: fatal error: pcl/apps/face_detection/openni_frame_source.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`

I know that with `gcc`, you can get the compiler to read to you where it looked for the include, but is there a way to accomplish this with `make` and `cmake`.

Comment: just pass the correct arg to gcc in the makefile?

Comment: I don't see gcc being called in my makefile. Also, would I have to make sure to add through cmake? It's the double layer of abstraction that's confusing me here, although it is quite possible that I'm approaching the question from the wrong direction here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Makefile` is automatically generated by CMake, you can launch `make` like this:

```
> make VERBOSE=1
```

to interleave the progression on targets with the actual commands `make` is executing.
From these commands you should be able to extract the current include paths.

You may probably want to take also a look at the [`include_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:include_directories) CMake command,
in case some include paths are missing.

Comment: This only shows the include trail up to which it was looking for a certain file. It doesn't tell you where it was trying to find the file that was not found.

Answer (score 2):

I'm cross-compiling a Win32 target on SUSE Linux using mingw32. None of the conventional verbose/debug options provided the `#include` search path.

This forced my (lazy) hand to manually reproduce the compile operation that ultimately revealed the header search path.

A brief description...

- Run the make operation and take note of the *compiler*, the *directory*, and the *command line* it's executing. Yeah, it's messy, but not impossible. Capture the output to a file if headless.
- Change into the directory
- Execute the compiler with the `--help` option. Take note of its *verbose* option.
- Run the compile command specifying the *verbose* option.

Here's what I got...

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/me/rpmbuild/BUILD/the-app-0.0.0/core/src/win32/include
 /home/me/rpmbuild/BUILD/the-app-0.0.0/core/src/win32/compat/include
 /home/me/rpmbuild/BUILD/the-app-0.0.0/core/src
 /home/me/rpmbuild/BUILD/the-app-0.0.0/core/src/win32/generic
 /home/me/rpmbuild/BUILD/the-app-0.0.0/core/src/win32/filed
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/include/c++
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-w64-mingw32
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/include/c++/backward
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/include
 /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.2.0/include-fixed
 /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include
End of search list.
```

Not too bad...

BTW, this is a cmake 3.5.2  configuration.

Comment: With MinGW on Windows you can also inspect the flags.txt file in the CMakeFiles directory.

Comment: Good to know, @André  -- I should have mentioned the build structure is the result of a `rpmbuild` operation.

Comment: Dude, this is gold! `--verbose` for intel compiler (icpx) btw. Thanks!